# Reading file line by line then hash them, gives wrong output in php

Tags: php, hash, md5

When i try to hash all my users password in my website, first i saved all passwords in file then i try to hash them, but I realize its give me wrong hash not the real one.

I've tried 2 function but same results, these PHP codes explain everything.

> File password.txt have just 1 line with "password" as a plain-text.

md5() function:

```
echo md5("password"); #5f4dcc3b5aa765d61d8327deb882cf99
```

file() function then md5 the line:

```
$openfile = file("password.txt");
foreach($openfile as $lines){
    echo md5($lines); #286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4
}
```

fopen() function:

```
if ($file = fopen("password.txt", "r")) {
    while(!feof($file)) {
        $lines = fgets($file);
        echo md5($lines); #286755fad04869ca523320acce0dc6a4
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

I think the line just have some blank spaces or something!?

**EDITED**

I have read more about the difference between hashing and encryption. And about hashing the password i use this now.

`md5(sha1($passwords . $various_salts))`

**EDITED**

These days, i started to use [password_hash()](https://www.php.net/password_hash) with BCrypt hashing algorithm without using MD5 or SHA1, its better now.

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt the entire file or each line?

Comment: MD5 isn't encryption, and you shouldn't **ever** use it for password hashing. "Adding salts later" won't fix anything, and writing bad code to fix later is how bad code winds up in production. Use http://php.net/password_hash instead.

Comment: You also shouldn't have a file full of plain text files.

Comment: Personally, I think you're wasting your time with this. Is this for educational purposes or intended to go live?

Comment: The whole "i know it's not secure but I'll add security later" philosophy is bad because later is always superseded with more urgent things that need to be done now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return values from both [`fgets`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php) and [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) include the line-endings.

You can either run the values through `rtrim($line, "\n");` first, or use the following option for `file`:

```
$openfile = file("little.txt", FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

which will remove the line-endings for you.

Edit:
As evidenced by the issues raised in the comments, this is a fairly strange approach to solving a problem. Think about why you need to store all these passwords in a single file (hashed or otherwise).

Comment: White space is a valid character for passwords right? Wouldn't `trim` remove that?

Comment: Generally yes, but if they're going to be stored in a single file then there's always going to be the issue of the separator overlapping with part of a password, whatever it is.

Comment: `rtrim($line, "\n");` assuming a newline is not a valid password character :-)

Comment: @AbraCadaver Fair point, that at least cuts the problem down a bit

Comment: trim would remove whitespace around a valid password.  I don't think that passwords like ___something____ are passwords anyone should allow.  Typically people don't allow passwords with any spaces whatsoever.  There is also a difference between spaces and all the other whitespace and non printable characters that someone might try and utilize.

Comment: And I guess depending on how the file was created `rtrim($line, "\r\n");`

Comment: @iainn Thanks bro, two way work in two codes xD i appreciate your help :)